# Circle in a v-shaped groove

Tags: geometry

[image: Geometry]

I have a circle in a v-shaped groove. I'm trying to calculate the radius `r` using only the `h2` dimension and the half-angle `a`.

Getting the radius using `h1` is simple using the right triangle formed by angle `a`, hypotenuse `h1` and opposite side `r`. How would I setup the geometry to use `h2` instead?

I can easily get the `d1` dimension, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You appear to have all the measurements already (apart from slight inaccuracies), so what’s the issue here?

Comment: Note that $\sin \alpha = \frac{r}{h_1} \Rightarrow h_1 = \frac{r}{\sin \alpha}$ and then $h_2 = r + h_1 = r + \frac{r}{\sin \alpha} = r \left( 1+ \frac{1}{\sin \alpha} \right)$.

Comment: @DavidQuinn The image is an example from CAD. In the real application I only know `a` and `h2`.

Comment: See the comments of @Matti P.

Comment: Express $h_2$ in terms of $r$ as follows:  $h_2 = \sqrt{2} r + r = (1 + \sqrt{2} ) r $.  Therefore, $r = \dfrac{h_2}{1 + \sqrt{2}} $

Comment: @MattiP. Ah, that's rather obvious when I see it. I was too set on going for a more geometric solution. Thanks!